# Laravel: How do I create the relationship and which one do I use?

Tags: php, laravel

I have the database structure that have a `classes` table, a `users` table and `users_classes` table that matches the other two, because a user can belong to multiple classes. I have a problem now. I have code like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Classes extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'classes';   

    public function students()
    {

    }             
}
```

And I want to be able to access the students of the class by typing `$class = Classes::find(1)` and then `$class->students` to access the students. How do I define the relationship without using the query builder? I want to use eloquent. Im a noobie in Laravel pls dont downvote.

Comment: you can use `return $this->hasMany(Player::class, 'player_id');`

Comment: Thats a [Many-to-Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a [`belongsToMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relation.

If your `users_classes` table has the fields `user_id` and `class_id` you can do the following:

```
public function students()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class, 'users_classes', 'class_id', 'user_id');
}
```